# Profinite completion of the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, profinite-groups, formal-completions

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\bN}{\mathbb N}
\DeclareMathOperator{\bZ}{\mathbb Z}
$Just playing around with [profinite completions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_group#Profinite_completion). As a basic example (ignoring the trivial case of finite groups or $\bZ$) I chose to compute the profinite completion of the $p$-adic integers, an infinite group I am more familiar with than others.

And here we go. The profinite completion of an arbitrary group $G$ is the projective limit over the system of quotients $G/N$ for $N\trianglelefteq G$ of finite index with the natural projection maps. Let us consider the case of the $p$-adic integers $\bZ_p$ and consider an arbitrary (normal) subgroup $N$ of finite index (I actually do not think the latter matters that much except for excluding $N=0$ which, OTOH, is important now that I think about it...). Certainly $N\ne0$ as the $\bZ_p$ is an infinite group. Hence we find $x\in N$ of minimal valuation $n=\nu_p(x)$ (recall that the valuation of $x\in\bZ_p\setminus\{0\}$ is defined as the minimal $n\in\bN$ such that $\pi_n(x)\equiv0\mod p^n$ with $\pi_n\colon\bZ_p\to\bZ/p^n\bZ$ as usual). As $n$ is minimal as such we have $\nu_p(y)\ge n$ for all $y\in N$ and hence $N\subseteq p^n \bZ_p$. From this argument we conclude that the quotients $\bZ_p/p^n\bZ_p\cong\bZ/p^n\bZ$ form a cofinal subsystem and hence it suffices to compute $\varprojlim\bZ_p/p^n\bZ_p\cong\varprojlim\bZ/p^n\bZ$. But this is simply $\bZ_p$ and we are done.

> Is the given argument correct? if not, where does it fail? I am not completely sure about the $N\subseteq p^n\bZ_p$-part implying the cofinal-part (even though I used this argument before and it appears to be correct there).
> **Bonus:** Is there a more sophisticated reason to consider only normal subgroups of *finite* index besides excluding the quotient $G/1\cong G$ (which renders the computation trivial immediately)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}$<s>The argument you gave is correct, and if fact shows something a little more than you claim. You chose $x\in N$ of minimal valuation $n:=\nu_p(x)$. This means that $x=up^n$ where $u\in\Z_p^\times$ is a unit, so not only is $N\subset p^n\Z_p$, but in fact, $N=p^n\Z_p$. That is, these don't just form a cofinal system of finite quotients; there are exactly all finite quotients.</s>

For you bonus question, you certainly want to exclude $G$ itself since otherwise your completion will just give back the original group, i.e. $G\cong\varprojlim\limits_{\text{all }N\triangleleft G} G/N$ for completely formal reasons. Considering finite quotients has the benefit that the group you get in the end will be compact, since it will be a closed subset of the compact space
$$\prod_{\substack{N\triangleleft G\\ [G:N]<\infty}}G/N,$$
where each $G/N$ is a finite space with discrete topology. Compact groups are especially nice, vaguely because compact spaces are nice and more concretely e.g. because you can do [Fourier analysis](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Pontryagin_duality) on them. You can also make sense of the "order" of a profinite group (given as a [supernatural number](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Supernatural_number), e.g. the order of $\Z_p$ is $p^\infty$) and talk about Lagrange's theorem and Sylow $p$-subgroups and the like from finite group theory. Hopefully this helps to motivate profinite completions.

As a side note, it is sometimes useful to form the inverse limit of only some finite quotients; one could take the limit of only the cyclic quotients (and talk of procyclic groups), of only the quotients with $p$-power order (and talk of pro-$p$ groups), etc.

Finally, I don't think computing the profinite completion of $\Z$ is as trivial as you suggest. Let $\widehat\Z$ denote this completion. Can you show that $\widehat\Z\cong\prod_p\Z_p$?

Edit: I made blunder in the first paragraph. It is not the case that all finite index subgroups are of the form $p^n\mathbb Z_p$ (when I wrote "in fact, $N=p^n\Z_p$" I somehow had switched to thinking about ideals in my mind). So where does this leave the claim about cofinality?

We would like to say that the quotients $\Z_p/p^n\Z_p$ form a cofinal sequence of finite quotients of $\Z_p$, i.e. if $\Z_p/N$ is a finite quotient, then our projective system includes a morphism $\Z_p/p^n\Z_p\twoheadrightarrow\Z_p/N$, i.e. $p^n\Z_p\subset N$ for some $n$. This is the reverse inclusion of what you showed. Unfortunately, I have not been able to convince myself one way or the other about this system actually being cofinal, but I figured I should include this edit anyways just to make it clear that what I initially said was incorrect (See edit 2).

As a general note, one thing one might do to avoid these issues is to define the profinite completion of a topological group $G$ to be the inverse limit of its finite-index, open subgroups. Then is the same definition when $G$ is finite, and has the added benefit that it is obvious that the profinite completion of a profinite group is itself under this definition.

Edit 2: Thanks to @TorstenSchoeneberg in the comments for pointing out how to actually answer your question. If $N$ is a subgroup of finite index $n$, then $nx\in N$ for any $x\in\Z_p$, so $N\supset n\Z_p=p^{v_p(n)}\Z_p$ and we have cofinality.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first part? I'm aware of an argument showing this for *closed* subgroups; I don't see right now how this generalizes to arbitrary subgroups. For the latter: I know that the profinite completion of $\mathbb Z$ is $\hat{\mathbb Z}$ (and, in fact, I know how to construct an isomorphism to $\prod_p\mathbb Z_p$) but it is more of definition than a computation (of course, depending on your POV).

Comment: After a little more thought, the first part of my post is incorrect. I was thinking about ideals and not arbitrary subgroups when I wrote it. This complicates things. To get the cofinality statement you want, you need that no matter how small $N$ is (i.e. no matter how big $\mathbb Z_p/N$ is), there's always some $p^n\mathbb Z_p$ that's smaller (i.e. some surjection $\mathbb Z_p/p^n\mathbb Z_p\to\mathbb Z_p/N$). This is the opposite direction from what you showed. See my (forthcoming) edit for the resolution.

Comment: I appreciate your edit! That being said, it points out a serious flaw in my thinking (which I am also not able to fix right away; but I will think about this). However, if I am not mistaken we have *open* $+$ *finite index* $\implies$ *closed* in which case I can handle the rest. Is this restriction common enough? Also, why does it suffice to only consider cyclic quotient? I am still not seeing this part.

Comment: If $N$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_p$ of finite index $n$, then $nx \in N$ for all $x \in \mathbb Z_p$, i.e. $N$ contains the open subgroup $n \mathbb Z_p = p^{v_p(n)} \mathbb Z_p$ and $n$ is a power of $p$. There are no non-open, finite index subgroups of $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks for the comment. That's a clever argument.

Comment: @mrtaurho Re: it sufficing to only consider cyclic quotients, that is just poor wording on my part in the answer. I only meant to indicate that in addition to profinite completions, people sometimes consider procyclic completions or pro-$p$ completions instead. I did not intend to suggest that these were the same thing in general.

Comment: @Niven Ah, I see. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Niven *$\DeclareMathOperator{\Z}{\Bbb Z}$ "i.e. if $\Z_p/N$ is a finite quotient, then our projective system includes a morphism $\Z_p/p^n\Z_p\twoheadrightarrow\Z_p/N$, i.e. $N\subset p^n\Z_p$ for some $n$"*; I think there is a typo here somewhere: I actually showed that $N\subseteq p^n\Z_p$ but we need the reverse inclusion (which Torsten Schoenberg provided). Anyways, I've convinced myself that *"If $N$ is a subgroup of finite index $n$, then $nx\in N$ for any $x\in\Z_p$"* holds (an interesting fact BTW) which yields the desired inclusion. Thanks again!

Comment: You're right, there is a typo.

Comment: Can I just point out that the profinite completion of a profinite group is not, in general, itself. It is a deep theorem of Nikolov-Segal that this is true for finitely generated profinite groups. This is because for them every finite-index subgroup is open. This depends on the Classification of Finite Simple Groups, and I think there's still no CFSG-free proof. There are easy examples on non-finitely generated profinite groups with subgroups that are of finite index but not open.